# US Tourist Visa denied to obtain Fiancé visa but can't get any

Tags: visas, usa, visa-refusals, tourist-visas

I visited the US this year March - June on Visa Waiver, total 88 days. During this period, I met someone who is now my girlfriend and we totally fell in love with each other. I returned back to Europe and then flew to the US again. Of course, they denied entry because it was too close from previous leave, and I didn't have a return ticket (I know, I should have).

I co-own a company in the UK, so I have strong ties to the UK.

I visited the embassy in London to get a tourist Visa with an honest reason. The interview took a long time; they probably were getting information about my entry denial, but finally they told me I should obtain a K1 Fiancé visa instead, so my Visa was denied. The problem is, she is legally still married, but separated and based on Louisiana law, her divorce will not be final until April next year. I want to visit her over Christmas and I wonder if it makes sense to try a Tourist Visa again in November. What more can I do for it? I tried to convince them that I want to do everything legally, but that didn't make any change (but I didn't tell them about divorce yet).

Comment: you are allowed to visit your fiancée, but as someone who intends to marry an American you are considered very high risk to just stay there. I know someone who visited her American fiancée from Canada several times without a Fiancée visa and without lying at the border (though she was advised not to wear her engagement ring and to use the word boyfriend rather than fiancée.)

Comment: @KateGregory point is that I am not able to legally enter the country now, as I was turned back with visa waiver (it's not valid anymore) and they denied my Visa. That's why I asked this question.

Comment: I didn't answer, but it's my opinion that you are not this person's fiancée (because she is not free to marry) and therefore the person who told you to get a fiancée visa is wrong. A simple tourist visa might be possible. But all I can do is tell you about someone else from a don't-need-a-visa country who visited a boyfriend in the US several times before marrying him.

Comment: Co-owning a company in the U.K. doesn’t necessarily show strong ties to U.K. and non immigrant intent in US, especially if you can spend 88 days away from it. What other ties do you have? Why can’t your gf visit you instead?

Comment: @KateGregory I entered too early and haven't return ticket, so I can't use visa waiver anymore. Also, we can be engaged as this is just oral promise to marry and there is no legal duties or rights from this. At least this is how I found it out on google. Should I not include her as Fiancee in Visa form?

Comment: @Traveller She has visited me for two weeks but as she has minor kids and they are attached to their Dad as well, it's complicated, even more during Christmas. So basically, she can but rare and short periods only. Of course, I have my family (parents, brother) here but those are not strong ties. No house, though.

Comment: The fiancee visa is appropriate if you intend to marry her and stay in the US as an immigrant.  Is that your intention?  If not, you should get a B-2 visitor visa.  What did you tell them that led them to indicate a fiancee visa?

Comment: @phoog yes, that is my intention, but not until mid of next year. I put her in Visa request form and also, when they asked me about purpose of my visit, I told them I want to visit my partner. That was what they were working with. Also, she asked me about plans, so I said I want to travel there in August and I have to be back in Europe at beginning of October. She just asked: and next? That's makes her to refuse visa.

I wonder if I can get single entry visa...?

Comment: @tomis probably your best bet at this point is to talk to a good immigration lawyer.  Strictly speaking, you can get a B-2 visa to enter the US even if you plan to marry and stay in the US, as long as you plan to do that on a subsequent trip.  The hard part is convincing the US government of your intentions.  Given your recent history, it is probably a more efficient use of your money to talk to a lawyer than to apply for a visa yourself.

Comment: @phoog Layer cannot help me convincing US gov, as this is only me, who will do the interview, right? I searched through internet for many cases saying the same, that people get B2 visa even planning marry the people. Do you think that bringing divorce confirmation from judge with confirming that divorce will be finalized any time in the future would help? Is there any way to get single entry visa even from multi-enter visa country (CZ, 10 years multi entry)?

Comment: @tomis a lawyer can answer the questions you posed in that comment, more authoritatively than can anyone on this site.  I can offer my opinion, but it isn't as valuable as that of a lawyer because I am not as familiar with the immigration system. More importantly, a lawyer can help you understand why you were refused, which seems unclear right now.  I doubt that the divorce papers would help you get a B visa; they'll probably be necessary for a K visa. As far as I can tell, asking for a single-entry B visa won't help at all.

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing more you can do. You almost certainly will be bounced if you apply for a visitor visa again because in your situation it is difficult to overcome the presumption of [immigrant intent](http://www.americanlaw.com/dintent.html). You've been denied entry and then refused a visitors visa in rapid succession. The fat lady has sung on visitors visas for a long while.

She can visit you in UK or you can meet in Canada.

Comment: Hopefully she is not in a state where her husband can file a lawsuit against you for [alienation of affection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alienation_of_affections)

Comment: Fortunately, husband is fine. Plus, LA is not in there.